# Qualtrics API functions not working within custom function called in EventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, qualtrics, onblur

I defined a custom function in the header section that checks, alerts the user, and resets the value of a particular slider bar when it fails certain restrictions.

This function works beautifully when called on question clicks:

```
  this.questionclick = chkVals;
```

I would like to also run the function when the user are exiting the text input field (as some users are using the keyboard to do the survey). I implemented an Event Listener for each sliders' text input field that runs the function when the focus is out of the text input field.

```
// choices is an array of choice ids 
  for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    var x = document.getElementById(choices[i]);
    x.addEventListener("blur", chkVals, true);
  };
```

I know that the event listener works, because the correct alerts are popping up. It is just not able to reset the values as `this.setChoiceValue` is not a function within the environment. I have tried setting `var that = this;` and calling `that.setChoiceValue` in the function, but it still does not work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the chkVals function declared globally? (I.e. just inside a <script> Tag?) 
Then you should be fine if you just use window.setChoiceValue instead of this.setChoiceValue.
Assuming that the setChoiceValue is also declared globally (i.e. just in a script tag, not as part of an object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@T. Gibbons 's answer helped me get to this point. As suggested I needed to add a parameter to `chkVals()` to be able to reference the `this` object. However,

```
this.questionClick = chkVals(this);
```

does not work due to `this` being a reserved object, so the whole header script will not run. I ended up changing all reference of `this` to `that` in my custom function and adding the parameter `that` as suggested:

```
function chkVals(that) {
...
... that.setChoiceValue(x, y)
}
```

To call the function with a parameter, I had to explicitly defined an anonymous function that called `chkVals`, otherwise it will not work (I am not sure why):

```
  var that = this; 

  this.questionclick = function() {chkVals(that);}

  for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
  var x = document.getElementById(choices[i]);
  x.addEventListener("blur", function() {chkVals(that);}, true);

  };
```

The above works!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown all your code, so I'm making some assumptions.

`this` is the Qualtrics question object in the addOnload function. Since chkVals is outside the addOnload function, `this` (or `that`) is undefined.  So, you need to pass it in your function call (`function chkVals(qobj)`) then use `qobj.setChoiceValue` in the chkVals function.  Then your function calls become:

```
this.questionClick = chkVals(this);
```

and

```
x.addEventListener("blur", chkVals(this), true);
```